# Texture mapping so close but not quite right

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, imagemagick, textures

I am building a raytracer and my texture mapping isn't quite right. Its very close though. I build a cup in blender and did a UV unwrap to display a texture. I exported the object and loaded it into my raytracer with the same texture. Here are two pictures:
[image: img]
[image: img]

As you can see the textures look very close, but something is off. If you look at the bottom of the cup on the sides you can see they aren't the same, but the textures are all aligned correctly so it does look somewhat right. The way the textures are calculated is by using barycentric coordinates.

```
    Vect n = getTriangleNormal();
    Vect ba = B.add(A.negative()).negative();
    Vect ca = C.add(A.negative()).negative();

    Vect ap = A.add(point.negative()).negative();
    Vect bp = B.add(point.negative()).negative();
    Vect cp = C.add(point.negative()).negative();


    double areaABC = n.dotProduct(ba.crossProduct(ca));
    double areaPBC = n.dotProduct(bp.crossProduct(cp));
    double areaPCA = n.dotProduct(cp.crossProduct(ap));

    if(areaABC < 0){areaABC = -areaABC;}
    if(areaPBC < 0){areaPBC = -areaPBC;}
    if(areaPCA < 0){areaPCA = -areaPCA;}

    double u = areaPBC / areaABC ; // alpha
    double v = areaPCA / areaABC ; // beta
    double w = 1.0f - u - v ; // gamma
```

Then to find the color I take the new point and map it onto the image

```
    Vect uv =  (textA.mult(u)).add(textB.mult(v)).add(textC.mult(w));
    int width = texture ->columns();
    int height = texture ->rows();


    double x = width * (uv.getX()) ; x = (int) x;
    double y = height * (1-uv.getY()) ; y = (int) y;

    //vector<unsigned int> c = texture -> getPixel(x,y); 

    //return Color(c[0]/255.0,c[1]/255.0,c[2]/255.0,0);

    int row = y;
    int column = x;

    Magick::PixelPacket *pixels = texture->getPixels(0, 0, width, height);
    Magick::Color color = pixels[width * row + column];

    double range = pow(2, texture -> modulusDepth());

    double r = color.redQuantum()/range ;
    double g = color.greenQuantum()/range ;
    double b = color.blueQuantum()/range ;

    return Color(r, g, b, 0);
```

Comment: First, your texture is reflected right-to-left. Besides, it looks like entire polygons are broken, are you sure they exported fine? Does it change when you move the camera? I'd start by testing for suspicious math results, like crossProduct==0, division by 0, etc.

Comment: oh, yeah. I can flip the reflection pretty easily. I have done other objects and the shapes come out correctly, just a texture issue. http://i.imgur.com/fEgZVlY.gifv

Comment: So if other objects works fine for you there's even bigger chance that the model is broken. Try to render UV values as colors and see if those polys are still broken.

Comment: have you tried disable `GL_CULL_FACE` ?